# How can i hide ActionLink Parameter or queryString from URL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

How can i hide query Parameters from URL?

I have three pages, I used `Context.Request.Query` to transfer data from `Page 1.cshtml` >> `Page 2.cshtml` >> `Page 3.cshtml` all works great. But I need your help on hiding the data from Url

In My View I have the following Code

```
var ProductID= Context.Request.Query["ProductID"];
var ProductName= Context.Request.Query["ProductName"];
```

and Action link to Navigate

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "Product", 
                   new { Area = "Products", 
                       id = ProductID,                           
                       ProductName = ProductName                        
                   }, 
                   new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

Comment: there're many ways to do this. may I ask the reason why you want to hide the querystring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comment said, there are many ways to achieve it,the key lies in your needs.

**One method**, If the parameters are passed from page1 `code behind in the controller`, then I suggest that you can directly archive the parameters you need to pass to **TempData**, so that you don't need to use actionlink to pass the parameters.

```
  public IActionResult Page1()
    {
        TempData["Area"] = "Products";
        TempData["id"] =1;
        TempData["ProductName"] = "name";
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        string Area = TempData["Area"] as string;
        int id = (int)TempData["id"];
        string ProductName = TempData["ProductName"] as string;
        return View();
    }
```

**Second method**, if allowed, you can put these parameters in the `form` to bind each value, if you don't want these values to be displayed, you can set them to `hidden` type.

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Product">
    <input id="Text1" type="hidden" name="Area" value="Products" />
    <input id="Text1" type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
    <input id="Text1" type="hidden" name="ProductName" value="name" />

    <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Create"  class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

Create action:

```
public IActionResult Create(string Area, int id, string ProductName)
    { 
        return View();
    }
```

**Third method**, if you must pass parameters from link to another view, then use **ajax** combined with **TempData**, please refer to the following case:

```
  public IActionResult Create(string Area, int id, string ProductName)
        {
            if (Area != null && id != 0 && ProductName != null)
            {
                TempData["Area"] = Area;
                TempData["id"] = id;
                TempData["ProductName"] = ProductName;
            }
            else
            {
                Area = TempData["Area"] as string;
                id = (int)TempData["id"];
                ProductName = TempData["ProductName"] as string;
            } 
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".mylink").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                var href = $(this).attr("href").split('?')[0];
                var query = $(this).attr("href").split('?')[1];
                var arr = query.split("&");
                result = {};
                for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    k = arr[i].split('=');
                    result[k[0]] = (k[1] || '');
                };
                $.ajax({
                    method: "Get",
                    url: href,
                    data: query,
                    success: function () {
                        window.location.href = href;
                    }
                });

            });

        })
    </script>
}
<h1>Index</h1>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "Product",
                       new
                       {
                           Area = "Products",
                           id = 1,
                           ProductName = "name"
                       },
                       new { @class = "btn btn-primary mylink" })
```

---

### Update for the second method:

After create action received these values from other view, you can use **model** or **ViewData** to display data in create view:

### Model

```
public class Test
{ 
   public int id{ get; set; }
   public string Area { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }  
}
```

Create action:

```
  public IActionResult Create(string Area, int id, string ProductName)
    { 
        Test myTest = new Test()
        {
            id = id,
            Area = Area,
            ProductName = ProductName
        };
        return View(myTest);
    }
```

Create view: (display value in a view)

```
@model WebApplication_core_mvc.Models.Test
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Create</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>Area</th>
          <th>ProductName</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.id</td>
        <td>@Model.Area</td>
        <td>@Model.ProductName</td>
    </tr>
```

### ViewData

Create action:

```
public IActionResult Create(string Area, int id, string ProductName)
        { 
            ViewData["id"] = id;
            ViewData["Area"] = Area;
            ViewData["ProductName"] = ProductName; 
            return View();
        }
```

Create view: (display value in a view)

```
@{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h1>Create</h1>


    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
           <th>id</th>
          <th>Area</th>
          <th>ProductName</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@ViewData["id"]</td>
            <td>@ViewData["Area"]</td>
            <td>@ViewData["ProductName"]</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I just saw your replay i will try that and let you know. Looks Great! Thank you the help!

Comment: Thank you again, On the second method how can i display passed values in a view?

Comment: @Rob, you can use `ViewData` or `create a model` to display these passed values in a view, I have updated my post, you can refer to it.

Comment: i tested it, and working i didn't try it all i know it will work for sure but Yongqing Yu you so helpful, your answers are very clear ..  you so awesome, Thank you so much

Comment: if you have any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355063/how-can-i-call-an-action-on-button-click