# How can i call an Action on button click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hi I have a form that used email address value as a search field, when email address exist in the system i want to populate a form.

I created this action to search by email address

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetContactByEmailID(string emailID)
        {

            if (emailID == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var Contacts = await ContactsService.GetContactsByEmailID(emailID);

            if (Contacts == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var ContactsDetail = Mapper.Map<Contact>(Contacts);

            return View(ContactsDetail);
        }
```

I need help on how Call the above action on button click and if exist i would like to display the Name of contact associated to the email address in the Name textbox

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="EmailAddress" class="col-6 form-control-label">Email</label>
      <input asp-for="EmailAddress" type="email" id="emailaddress" >
       <button class="btn" role="button">Search</button>
  </div>
```

The following is where i want to display the selected contact Name

```
<form>
   <div class="col-sm-5 m-b">
     <label for="Name" class="col-sm-10 form-control-label required">Full Name</label>
      <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control form-control" id="Name" placeholder="">
     <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution in razor page. change code to accommodate model and database need:

Page-Code behind:

```
public class AboutModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Email = "Enter email to search here";
    }

    public JsonResult OnGetContactByEmailID(string emailid)
    {
        // get name based on email;
        return new JsonResult("Arun");
    }
}
```

Page View Code -

```
@page
@model AboutModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<br /> 
<br/>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="EmailAddress" class="col-6 form-control-label">Email</label>
    <input asp-for="Email" type="email" id="emailaddress">
    <button class="btn" role="button" onclick="search()">Search</button>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-5 m-b">
    <label for="Name" class="col-sm-10 form-control-label required">Full Name</label>
    <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control form-control" id="Name" placeholder="">
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function search() {
        if ($('#emailaddress').val() != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                url: "/?handler=ContactByEmailID",
                data: { 'emailID': $('#emailaddress').val() },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#Name').val(response);
                    // set json result to selected contact Name
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Output Here :

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215868/discussion-on-answer-by-always-a-learner-how-can-i-call-an-action-on-button-clic).

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the form or whatever it is you are working with, without refreshing the page, you need to implement an asynchronous method to get the contact details, and add the result to the DOM.

I like to use partial views for this purpose.

The flow is like this:

A user inputs an e-mail address, clicks on the Search button. An Ajax request will be send to the appropriate method, this method return a partial view.
When it returns data to the Ajax caller, we insert the result into a div with the id '#target'

```cs
     public async Task<IActionResult> GetContactByEmailID(string emailID)
            {

                if (emailID == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                var Contacts = await ContactsService.GetContactsByEmailID(emailID);

                if (Contacts == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                var ContactsDetail = Mapper.Map<Contact>(Contacts);

                return Partial("_ContactDetails", ContactsDetail);
            }
```

```cs
// Partial view inside Views/Shared: _ContactDetails.cshtml

@Model ContactsDetail

<label>Full name</label>
<p>@model.FullName</p>
```

```cs
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="EmailAddress" class="col-6 form-control-label">Email</label>
      <input asp-for="EmailAddress" type="email" id="emailaddress" >
       <button id="searchButton" class="btn" role="button">Search</button>
  </div>

<form>
   <div class="col-sm-5 m-b">
     <label for="Name" class="col-sm-10 form-control-label required">Full Name</label>

      // Here it will add the partial view to the page, if the Ajax call is successful.
      <div id="target"></div>

      <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control form-control" id="Name" placeholder="">
     <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $('#searchButton').on('click', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/home/GetContactDetailById'
                data: { 'emailId' : '$("#EmailAddress").val()' }
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#target').html(result);
                },
                datatype: 'json'
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis, What i am trying to accomplish is On create new record page i have email address when you enter that and submit display selected email address information next to the form, In Create view call `GetContactByEmailID` and display the result on the same page

Comment: Ah I see, it wasn't really clear from your question. In that case you can use jquery to capture the click on the button,  send an asynchronous ajax request to a method that either returns a partial view or a JsonResult, and update the DOM by using jquery to append the result.

Comment: Thanks Dennis!! I am trying it, do i have to include asp-area? search click nothing happen

Comment: no luck Dennis  nothing happen when i click search button, but still trying this is the kind of solution i was looking for

Comment: for updating single filed , partial view is not efficient solution, you should send ajax call and set field value in success response of ajax.

Comment: @Always_a_learner agreed, in this case the solution without a partial view is going to be more efficient. My answer aims more for re-usability because Rob did say he wanted '(to) display selected email address information next to the form'.  And not just a single value.